# Prism EventAggregator and MVVM Light Messenger Summary

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light, eventaggregator

Can someone please give me good overview of the Prism EventAggregator in comparison to the MVVM Light Messenger service? Specifically;

- Are they similiar things, or meant for wholly different purposes?
- The pros and cons of both
- Where they should and should not be used
- Use in modular development, such as when used in conjunction with MEF or Unity
- Other information you deem relevant

This is something that I have not seen addressed much, and I find myself still using both in the same project, when my gut feel says I should use one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EventAggregator and Messenger are similar. They both are used to decouple the communication between different components which are used in a composite application. in most cases they both offer similar features.

Messenger has the option of brodcasting to all the subscribers or to targetted subscribers using a key. I am not sure if such a feature exists in EventAggregator.

In terms of Pros and Cons, MVVMLight is very lightweight. Prism comes with other related dll's. If your don't want to use all the features of Prism you can just make use of EventAggregator.

Althought I haven't used any of these frameworks with MEF or Unity, but since they are lke utilities / helpers / addins or whatever you call they should be able to work.

Comment: I used both successfully too. I usually just extracted the pieces I needed from MVVM Light/Prism, so both were pretty lightweight, although I think Messenger might have been a little bit smaller. There might be some minor performance considerations if you are going to be raising lots of events, but you would probably have to write some code to compare them. One problem I have with the EventAggregator is that on Windows Phone I have to make my handled and filter callbacks public - otherwise I get method access exceptions and these methods don't make sense as public. Not sure of MVVM Light here.